# Need help in javascript code

Tags: .net, asp.net, javascript

```
var radiobox = document.getElementById('<%=rdoRiskAccepted.ClientID%>');

            alert(radiobox[0].checked);
```

I am getting undefined as a alert. what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Basic debugging first. Any errors in the error console? Is the ID you are using actually output in the browser, and is there a radio button with that ID?

Comment: Try putting <%=rdoRiskAccepted.ClientID%> in an invisible text box (with style="display:none") and then access the id of the text box. I don't think javascript can access .net variables (allthought I do not know much about .net so I could be flagrantly wrong).
Second thought, pass is as a variable in js function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getElementById` returns a single element because, even for radio groups, [the `id` attribute **must** be unique](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2).  You should use the `name` attribute to specify a radio group and use `getElementsByName` instead.  For instance:

```
<input type="radio" name="myRadio" checked><label>1</label>
<input type="radio" name="myRadio"><label>2</label>
```

JS

```
var radiobox = document.getElementsByName("myRadio");
alert(radiobox[0].checked);
```

Comment: I am using asp:radiobuttonlist, so I would have ID only...no name

Comment: seriously? ASP doesn't give you access to the name? well, if so, just use the ID to get the first one, then access the .name property to get the name of the radio button set, then access by index.

Comment: @vaibhav: I don't work with ASP, but your ASP.net markup would still have to render into valid HTML code.  According to some of the pages I've read, radio buttons are rendered with the `id` of the list as their `name`, so using `document.getElementsByName('<%=rdoRiskAccepted.ClientID%>');` should work.

Answer (score 1):

use alert(radiobox .checked);

I would also like to know why you are using clientid only you have to use <%=this.page.clientid + "_" + rdoRiskAccepted.ClientID%>

Comment: rdoRiskAccepted.ClientID will return the complete client side ID of the control, with page/content placeholder etc IDs in place.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery...

```
<asp:radiobuttonlist ID="rdoRiskAccepted" runat="server">
    <asp:listitem Value="True" Selected="true">Yes</asp:listitem>
    <asp:listitem Value="False">No</asp:listitem>
</asp:radiobuttonlist>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function(){
    var riskAccepted=$('#<%=rdoRiskAccepted.ClientID%> input');
    alert(riskAccepted[0].checked); //true
});
//]]>
</script>
```